# Hosted Exchange 2010 Send As

Tags: exchange-2010, hosted

I have a hosted exchange 2010 and I am trying to setup the Send-As permission.

I am following the [*Manage Send As Permissions for a Mailbox* Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676368.aspx), which basically describes the commands for achieving this.

I have user accounts `aaa` and `bbb`

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailbox -organization myorg -identity "aaa"
Name                      Alias                ServerName       ProhibitSendQuota
----                      -----                ----------       -----------------
aaa                       aaa                  mx1  4.95 GB (5,315,022,848 bytes)


[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailbox -organization myorg-identity "bbb"
Name                      Alias                ServerName       ProhibitSendQuota
----                      -----                ----------       -----------------
bbb                       bbb                  mx1  4.95 GB (5,315,022,848 bytes)
```

Now, when I use the command below to give `bbb` permission to send-as `aaa`, I get the following error:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-mailbox -organization myorg -identity "aaa" | Add-ADPermission -Extended Rights "Send As" -user "bbb"

mx1/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations/myorg/aaa wasn't found. 
Please make sure you've typed it correctly.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : D2FD338,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddADPermission
```

The error message that `aaa` was not found does not make sense, because I just retrieved the mailbox in the previous commands.

I have tried using email addresses instead of alias as well, but that does not work either.

Comment: I found the answer: <br>Reading further ...i found the answer to be partly from

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff935839.aspx

It appears that I have to use a different command which does the same thing: Add-RecipientPermission "Help Desk" -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee "Ayla Kol"

but for my case, i had to specify the whole organisation etc

Add-RecipientPermission "domain/Microsof Exchange Hosted Organizations/myOrg/Help Desk" -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee "Ayla Kol"

:)

Comment: You can post that as an answer and mark it as accepted, we allow that around here. Though I think you need to wait 48 hours after the questions is posted to actually accept. It lets the system know this question has an answer, so won't recycle it periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Reading further I found the answer to be partially from

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff935839.aspx

It appears that I have to use a different command which does the same thing:
Add-RecipientPermission "Help Desk" -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee "Ayla Kol"

but in my case, I had to specify the whole organisation etc

Add-RecipientPermission "domain/Microsof Exchange Hosted Organizations/myOrHelp Desk" -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee "Ayla Kol"

Comment: Is this solved? If it is, please tick the check mark to indicate so to others. If it is not, please make it clear in your question what more needs to be answered.